# How to compile a ipk file into a image in yocto?

Tags: compilation, package, yocto

I'm working on RDK-B (based on yocto). There is a recipe (let's say my_package_1.0.bb) that builds libraries and populates sysroot with libraries and headers I need for development. I also see that .ipk for my package is created under build/tmp/deploy/ipk/.

My requirement is, I want to share the libraries, headers and a recipe that deploys these in my customer's sysroot directory (for their development), but not the sources for my package. How can I provide the my_package ipk file I created and compile it into the image? How to change the current recipe to use the ipk file instead of source code?
It would be better if there is an example for reference.

Thank you very much.